# Changing ytic font size in gnuplot epslatex (multiplot)

Tags: gnuplot

I have problems changing the font size of my ytics (xtics as well) in an epslatex gnuplot.

I tried set format y `'\tiny{%g}'`
It is only working for the first of the two plots.

This is my code:

```
set terminal epslatex
set output "w_alt_nsyB_multi.tex"
set multiplot layout 1,1
set xrange [-0.5:17]
set yrange [0:110]
set xlabel "days" 
set ylabel "Survival (\\%)" offset 2.5
set key reverse 
set xtics font 'Arial,4' s
et style histogram errorbars gap 2 lw 1
set style data histogram
set style fill solid 1 border lt -1
set boxwidth 0.8
plot 'w_alt_nsyB.dat' every ::::7 using 2:3:xticlabels(1) title 'w1118'  lt rgb "#000000",\
  'w_alt_nsyB.dat' every ::::7 using 4:5 title 'wtSYN'  lt rgb "#FF0000",\
'w_alt_elav_endoG.dat' every ::::7 using 6:7 title '38085'  lt rgb "#9400D3"
set origin 0.5, 0.25
set size 0.5, 0.5
set xrange [-0.5:6]
set yrange [0:110]
set xlabel "\\tiny{Time of $Mn^{2+}$ treatment}"
set ytics ('10'10,'50'50,'100'100) nomirror
unset border
set xtics nomirror
unset ylabel
unset key
plot 'w_alt_nsyB_100.dat' using 2:3:xticlabels(1) lt rgb "#000000",\
 'w_alt_nsyB_100.dat' using 4:5:xticlabels(1) lt rgb "#FF0000",\
 'w_alt_nsyB_100.dat' using 6:7:xticlabels(1) lt rgb "#9400D3"
unset multiplot
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The format applies only to the automatic tics, but for the second plot you set manual ytics

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

set ytics format '\tiny{%g}' ('10'10,'50'50,'100'100) nomirror

did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format given in `set format ...` isn't applied if you give an explicit manual label like you do with

```
set ytics ('10'10,'50'50,'100'100)
```

You must either just give the locations of the labels

```
set format y '\tiny %g'
set ytics (10, 50, 100)
```

or include the font macro in every manual label

```
set ytics ('\tiny 10' 10, '\tiny 50' 50, '\tiny 100' 100)
```

Note also, that your syntax `\tiny{%g}` is wrong, `\tiny` is only a switch and doesn't take any arguments. In this case it doesn't matter, because every label is wrapped in an individual LaTeX box, but in other situations it makes a big difference. To wrap the tiny font you would usually need `{\tiny %g}`.

The same happens for the explicit labels which are set with `xticlabel`. Also here, the format from `set format x` doesn't apply. Instead of giving a column number to `xticlabel` (like `xticlabel(1)` in your example), you must give the complete label string including the macro:

```
xl(c) = sprintf('\tiny %s', strcol(c))
plot 'file.dat' using 2:3:xticlabel(xl(1))
```

Next time, please give a *minimal* example which allows others to reproduce your problem. We don't have your data files to run the script. And your problem isn't related to you specific data file, so you can as well construct an example using functions, which possibly leads you itself to the solution...

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the quick reply it works perfectly. 
Can you also tell me how to change the size of the xtics?
set format x '\tiny %g'
does not work, maybe it has something to do with the use of xticlabels(1) ?!?